# How could I get info about Generation of already created Hyper-V VM?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

Hyper-V UI has not any option to get info about generation of VM that was used during first setup. I do believe it should be somewhere in Settings, but can't find anything.
I'm using Hyper-V service on Windows 10 host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done by using Windows PowerShell as an Administrator.
The command is `Get-VM`, but, for getting info about Generation you have to add `Format-List`:

`PS C:\> Get-VM | Format-List` will show complex info including Generation.